# Run a .bat file from a vbs without having to specify its drive C:

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I am asking you guys how to run a `.bat` file from a `.vbs` without having to specify its containing drive `C:`. I want to try to make some sort of installation and I did a fake loading or installing screen that a `.bat` file opens up and does its mini animation from `.vbs`. The problem about this is when I send this `.vbs` with the `.bat` it always says that an error occurred; and this is what I found:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Thingy.bat""")
```

The problem with this script is that the person I send it to will also need the same name as I and in `C:`. How can I change this script, or is it impossible?

Comment: If it always lands on the Desktop you could use `%USERPROFILE%` or the equivalent of that in vbs...

Comment: Get the script path into a variable. `scriptPath = FSO.GetParentFolderName(wscript.ScriptFullName)`

Answer (score 0):

Next *commented* code snippet should do the job (most statements and commands are itemized for the sake of comprehensibility):

```
option explicit
On Error GoTo 0

    ' declare variables
Dim WshShell, sUserProfile, strCommand, fso

    ' assign all object references to appropriate variables 
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso      = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' get an environment variable's expanded value
sUserProfile = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserProfile%")

    ' build command to run
strCommand = """" _
        & fso.BuildPath( fso.BuildPath( sUserProfile, "Desktop"), "Thingy.bat") & """"

Wscript.Echo "(debug) command to run" & vbNewLine & strCommand

WshShell.Run strCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

If the batch file is always on the desktop,you should use **%userprofile%** like this way :

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run(chr(34) & "%userprofile%\Desktop\Thingy.bat" & chr(34))
```

Or something like that when the batch file and the vbscript file are both in the same folder :

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
scriptPath = FSO.GetParentFolderName(wscript.ScriptFullName)
wscript.echo scriptPath
MyBatchFile = chr(34) & scriptPath & "\Thingy.bat" & chr(34)
wscript.echo MyBatchFile
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run(MyBatchFile)
```